# Not changing automatically background image jquery

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change automatically the background image from a website, but everytime it should be changed I am getting this error:

GET http://localhost:8383/img/fotoHeader2.jpg net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I have tried to change the path of the images but it doesn´t work anyways. Do you know how to fix this?

Here is the code:

```
var imageFile = ["fotoHeader.jpg", "fotoHeader1.jpg", "fotoHeader2.jpg"];
var currentIndex = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    if (currentIndex == imageFile.length) {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }

    $(".fotoHeader").css('background-image','url(../img/' + imageFile[currentIndex] + ')');
    currentIndex++;
}, 5000);
```

And this is directory structure:

[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ntnQ.png)

Comment: can you share your directory/folder structure

Comment: Sure, done @NickParsons

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change this line:

```
$(".fotoHeader").css('background-image','url(../img/' + imageFile[currentIndex] + ')');
```

to this:

```
var bgImage = 'url(../img/' + imageFile[currentIndex] + ')';
console.log(bgImage);
$(".fotoHeader").css('background-image',bgImage);
```

so you can console.log your url on browser console, and then put it in css code see if it is working:

```
.fotoHeader{
    background-image: put one of your console.log result here;
}
```

by the way, which file did you put your js code in? main.js or index.html?